# ng-model is being shared inside table due to nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having some issues with using ng-model inside table. Table is constructed from data i got from Server using RESTful API Service, here are details of data that i am using:

- Insurance Plans that i fetched from the server and that i am storing
  inside `insurancePlans` array
- Insurance Items that i fetched from the server and that i am storing
  inside `insuranceItems` array

**NOTE** : *Every Insurance Plans has list of Insurance Items!*

Here is the HTML code:

```
<table class="table" ng-init="$parent.getInsurancePlans();$parent.getInsuranceItems()">
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col ng-repeat="plan in $parent.insurancePlans" class="ng-class: $parent.selectedCol==$index ? 'selected-col' : ''">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th class="centered-cell" ng-repeat="plan in $parent.insurancePlans">{{plan.name}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in $parent.insuranceItems track by $index">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td class="centered-cell" ng-repeat="plan in $parent.insurancePlans track by $index" ng-click="$parent.setSelectedColumn($index)">
                <img src="images/check.png" ng-show="$parent.showImg(plan.insuranceItems, item)"></img>
                <input contenteditable type="checkbox" checklist-model="selectedOptionalItems" checklist-value="item" ng-show="$parent.showCheckBox(item,plan)"  id="optional-insurance-plans" name="optionalInsurancePlans"/>
                <select contenteditable ng-model="selectedFranchiseOption[$parent.$index]" ng-show="$parent.showSelectOptions(plan,plan.insuranceItems, item)" class="form-control" name="franchise-options" id="franchise-options" required>
                    <option value="{{0}}">0</option>
                    <option value="{{item.franchise/2}}">{{item.franchise/2}}</option>
                    <option value="{{item.franchise}}">{{item.franchise}}</option>
                </select>
                <div ng-show="$parent.showFranchise(plan,plan.insuranceItems, item)" name="franchise" id="franchise">{{item.franchise}}</div>                                   
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

These `ng-show` attributes are there for a reason, but you don't need to pay any attention to them because i am 100% sure they are not relevant to the problem i am having.

[image: Each Insurance Plan has it's own list of Insurance Items]

Here is the initial look of the table. Now, notice that **PRIVILEGE** Insurnace Plans have check boxes associated with the last 4 insurance items, that means each insurance item is optional for each of the insurance plans that are associated with that item.

- **PROBLEM**: If i check Insurance Item `Juridic protection` for Insurance Plan `PRIVILAGE A`  here is what happens:

[image: Ng-model being shared for all insurance plans]

I am aware that i am using nested ng-repeat and that for each Insurance Plan that contains current insurance item`checklist-model="selectedOptionalItems"` will be shared, in other words all elements inside the same row will be populated with the same value. The same thing happens when i select one of the options in dropdown menu. Here is a picture of that problem aswell:
[image: When i select a item from dropdown menu, every Insurance Plan which contains that Insurance Item will share the selected value]

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: `checklist-value="item"`, `item` is in the first `ng-repeat`. `ng-model="selectedFranchiseOption[$index]"`, where does `$index` come from? First or Second `ng-repeat`?

Comment: To be honest i just fixed that like 2 minutes ago. Current code : `ng-model="selectedFranchiseOption[$parent.$index]"` . So `$parent.$index` is first `ng-repeat`, but now i have the same problem as i do with checking the check box item, every Insurance Plan that shares that item gets the same selected value.

Comment: Of course, they're on the same `row`, and the `$parent.$index` is the same for all `plan`s on the same row. You need to bind `ng-model` to the `plan`s instead for them to be unique.

Comment: Could you maybe edit the code posted in the question, because i am not sure what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: If you can post a link to e.g. jsfiddle with a "working" example of the problem, I can help you edit that.

Comment: I actually figured out what you mean, and it works! all i did was `ng-model="plan.selectedFranchiseOption[$parent.$index]"` , Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, no problem! Acctually made a small JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/mjbe4516/